# reCAPTCHA doesn't work : Invalid API parameter(s). Try reloading the page

Tags: google-chrome, web, recaptcha, captcha

When I go on every website that has a captcha, I keep getting the "Invalid API parameter(s). Try reloading the page." error message. I even did the test at https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/

Please help, it's been over a month since i have this problem... Thanks.

Comment: Works for me, can you send a screen shot of what is shown your end?

Comment: Currently experiencing this as well.  Works on Chrome and Firefox, but dies in Safari.